# trying to add style using js, would this be the correct way in using it?

Tags: javascript

Code Follows :-

```
function justDoIt(){

    var toDos = $('.js-complete').addClass('complete');
    toDos.parent().removeClass('hidden');
    var complete = document.getElementById("complete");
    elem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
 }
 // ('complete').style.textDecoration = "line-through";

 justDoIt();
```

Comment: The `.style.textDecoration = "line-through";` part should work, but your `elem` variable isn't declared anywhere - should it be `complete`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to create a check-list and if a item is checked off i want the style "line-through" to go through it. If that makes any sense.

Comment: so are you saying it should be `complete.style.textDecoration = "line-through"`?

Comment: Yes, `complete.style.textDecoration = "line-through"`. Note: element IDs need to be unique, so if you have a list of items it wouldn't work if more than one had the ID `"complete"` - you should use classes for that.

Comment: First half of your function uses jQuery and the second one uses vanilla JS for DOM manipulation. Consider replacing the second part to `$("#complete").css("text-decoration", "line-through")` for consistency and your own convenience. Either use jQuery everywhere or do not use.